# How to append ajax response in the unknown element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have several `<div>` without class name. something like this: (`*` is where I want to append ajax response)

```
<div>
<div> text 1</div>
<div> text 2 </div>
<div> * <h1></h1> </div>
<div> text 3 </div>
</div>
```

The only clue that I have is `<h1>`. because the number of `<div>` is not constant (sometimes I have just 1 `div`). In other word, How can I select `div` that is containing `<h1>` and then append ajax response at the beginning of that ?

Comment: Try adding a bit more code. Include js and html code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery `has` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has/). In this cae you can find your element like this:

```
var yourElement = $('div').has('h1');
```

If you want to add some data that you receive from AJAX request, you can use method [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
var resultFromAjax = 'some result';
var yourElement = $('div').has('h1');
yourElement.prepend(resultFromAjax);
```

Comment: good ! just one thing, can I use `has()` with two element ? something like this: `$('div').has('h1 && h2');` ?

Comment: @Sajad Where on html is h2 element?

Comment: there is not, I just want to know, is it possible to I use `has()` for two elements ?

Comment: Just chain as many as you like. `$('div').has('h1').has('h2');`

Comment: Or if you want to get either one or another use [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: oh sorry, I did not ask my question as well, I edited it, can you answer me ? (all my `<div>` are enclose in the one `<div>`)

Answer (score 0):

To choose this `h1` from `div` you can simply use this jQuery code:

`var h1 = $("div > h1")`

or

`var h1 = $("div h1")`